# React native and expo logic

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I see react native crossing to expo. Expo can build android and ios without android and ios files. If i add new library for example sqlite how can i react native link without android and ios file  in react native expo. Can anybody tell me expo and react native logic

Comment: expo make react native build environment much easier, you can still access ios and android files by running the expo eject. Expo is just a helping tool for building react native apps

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cant. Any library that need to be link to native cannot be done on Expo. You need to eject it.

The way Expo works is that they maintain the ios and android folder for you. This way you don't have to worry about the native stuff. You can just concentrate on Javascript.

The downside of this is when you have a library that needs to change the native code, you have no way of linking it because as you say you don't have the android and ios folder.